# How to fix this C++ thread global declaration/definition?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-local

This is my simple C++ code.

When I compile in Linux, I get this error only for `t_vec_g` variable. I do not understand this error. I want to have threal_local storage with global scope with in the thread.

Why are `t_in_g` and `t_vec_l` are correct and `t_vec_g` is error?

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp

test.cpp:6:41: error: non-local variable ‘t_vec_g’ declared ‘__thread’ needs dynamic initialization static __thread vector<int> t_vec_g(10,3);

test.cpp:6:29: note: C++11 ‘thread_local’ allows dynamic initialization and destruction
 static __thread vector<int> t_vec_g(10,3);
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

static __thread vector<int> t_vec_g(10,100);
static __thread int t_in_g = 200;

main(int agrc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{

        static __thread vector<int> t_vec_l(10,300);
        static __thread int t_in_l = 400;

        cout << t_in_l << endl;
        cout << t_vec_l[0] << endl;
        cout << t_in_g << endl;
        cout << t_vec_g[0] << endl;
}
```

Comment: The error message seems clear to me: `t_vec_g` requires dynamic initialization (running a constructor), while `t_in_g` does not. `__thread` apparently doesn't support that. The message is even nice enough to provide a solution: use `thread_local`

Comment: More specifically, __thread doesn't support dynamic initialization of non-local (in this case, global) variables. It does support dynamic initialization of local variables (hence why t_vec_l does not report an error).

Comment: @Nerdizzle    I thought about it.  Then, I was thinking what's the big deal in providing the support.  That's where I thought I was missing some silly syntax or something. So, what exactly is the purpose of __thread ?  If I replace with thread_local  in  all 4 declarations, It just compiles...